# Where to place deferred completion closure in try/catch in swift

Tags: swift, closures, realm

I am at a bit of a loss as to how the following code will run. My intention is that the onCompletion is executed only if the try succeeds. So should the defer closure be inside the try or after it? - Or am I completely on the wrong track.

This...

```
func addUserActivity(aUserActivity:UserActivity, onError:OnError, onCompletion: (Void) -> (Void)) {
        if let database = database {
            do {
                try database.write({
                    database.add(aUserActivity)
                    defer {
                        onCompletion()
                    }
                })
            } catch {
                onError(message: "Realm error",informativeText: "Realm database failed to write object")
            }
        }
    }
```

Or this...

```
func addUserActivity(aUserActivity:UserActivity, onError:OnError, onCompletion: (Void) -> (Void)) {
        if let database = database {
            do {
                try database.write({
                    database.add(aUserActivity)
                })
                defer {
                    onCompletion()
                }
            } catch {
                onError(message: "Realm error",informativeText: "Realm database failed to write object")
            }
        }
    }
```

Or something completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In either case the `defer` is not necessary. You can simply write `onCompletion()`.

If you call `onCompletion()` inside the `write` block, it will *always* be executed, but if you write it after the `try database.write{...}` then the onCompletion will be skipped if the `write` throws an error, which sounds like your desired behavior.

(edited by OP to include final solution)

**SOLUTION**

```
func addUserActivity(aUserActivity:UserActivity, onError:OnError, onCompletion: (Void) -> (Void)) {
        if let database = database {
            do {
                try database.write({
                    database.add(aUserActivity)
                })
                onCompletion()
            } catch {
                onError(message: "Realm error",informativeText: "Realm database failed to write object")
            }
        } 
    }
```